# Ubuntu 20.04 settings will not open

Tags: 20.04, settings

My Settings will not open.
When I enter `sudo gnome-control-center`
I get this error

```
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: _ZThn16_N9Inspector22InspectorDebuggerAgent8stepNextERN3WTF6StringE
```

I tried

`sudo mv /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib.old` and `sudo mv /usr/local/lib`
and get this

```
mv: missing destination file operand after '/usr/local/lib'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

Had used ubuntu in the last version forever and not messed much with terminal.  I have had to reinstall this twice so far.  This solution i tried is the only one I can find attached to an error like mine.  Any thoughts

---

```
tim@toshiba:~$ ldd $(which gnome-control-center) | grep local; dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37; ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep local 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
```

Comment: You should not run `gnome-control-center` as root. Please add output of `ldd $(which gnome-control-center) | grep local`; `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37`; `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep local` to the question.

Comment: By root you mean sudo?

Comment: Yes. Please add output of `ldd $(which gnome-control-center) | grep local; dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37; ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep local` .

Comment: Sorry this took so long Here is the input and output      tim@toshiba:~$ ldd $(which gnome-control-center) | grep local; dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37; ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep local
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37